# Find the number of IPs connected to a port using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, tcp

The following command tells you which IP addresses are connected to port 1234 and how many connections there are from each IP address.

```
netstat -plan|grep :1234|awk {'print $5'}|cut -d: -f 1|sort|uniq -c|sort -nk 1
```

**Results**

```
1 0.0.0.0
1 107.123.93.244
1 107.123.141.5
1 107.123.228.217
1 108.123.198.185
1 109.123.142.131
```

How can we collect the same information from within Node.js?

Comment: Node.js is not a replacement for administrative tools, why not use what is already available? If you insist, look into this module: https://www.npmjs.org/package/netstat . Also be aware: "You will need netstat installed, this is not a replacement for netstat; just a wrapper. On most unix-like systems it should be provided by default by the net-tools package."

Comment: @alandarev I'll want a convenient page to show the IP addresses connected to 10 different ports, so having node show it on a webpage will be better than running the unix command 10 times and try to make sense of the data. Can the output of the command be captured and pased into object/arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute commands via node's [child_process module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).  For example, using the [spawn function](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) you can string together command (meaning pipe the output of one command to another commands input).  You're command has quite a lot of pipe's, but as an example from the docs, here's how you could run `ps ax | grep ssh`:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ps    = spawn('ps', ['ax']),
    grep  = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

ps.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
});

ps.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('ps process exited with code ' + code);
  }
  grep.stdin.end();
});

grep.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('' + data);
});

grep.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('grep stderr: ' + data);
});

grep.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('grep process exited with code ' + code);
  }
});
```

As for your next question:

> Can the output of the command be captured and pased into object/arrays?

When you get the data on your last command (since you'll be sending each command's `stdout` to the next command's `stdin`), you can parse the string to grab the individual lines of text.  For example:

```
var os = require("os");

finalCommand.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    // convert all the output to a single string
    var output = data.toString();

    // split the output by line
    output = output.split(os.EOL);

    // parse each line... etc...
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        // output for example...
        console.log(output[i]);

        // etc...
    }
});
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea on how you can string commands together, and once the command has completed, parse the output.  Does that help?